# LCD: do black pixels spend energy?

Tags: lcd

Does displaying black screen (but not turned off), consume less power than a white screen? Or is the screen just blocking light to show a black pixel and not blocking for not showing it?

And, if I go to the command line in Linux (tty3), would the monitor spend less energy?

Answer (score 5):

On an LCD monitor, liquid crystal *blocks* light from a backlight, provided by white fluorescent tubes or, more commonly now, white LEDs. Therefore a black pixel doesn't reduce power usage in and of itself.

If a monitor is displaying all-black, most will reduce power to the backlight accordingly, primarily to produce a deeper black, and of course also to save power.

There's [a question on Skeptics.StackExchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4373/43) discussing this concept.

Comment: At least on passive LCD displays, energized pixels or segments use up noticeably more power than non-energized ones; I'm not sure about TFT displays.  The power difference is tiny compared with the power used by a typical backlight, but can be important in battery-powered applications.  A certain portion of display current consumption is also proportional to the number of separately-scanned rows; some display controllers can save power by partially-blanking the display, but such abilities are not generally well supported (I'm not sure why).